# Django User model with different types that may have same usernames?

Tags: django, django-users

I have a db where there are different tables for 3 different groups of accounts: parents, teachers, schools.

I would like to build a User model for those 3 types of users. Usernames for all accounts will be pk of each data. The problem is that accounts are from 3 different tables, which have same pks. Is there a way to make a login with composite username (username + user_role)?

My User Model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    db = 'default'
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'School'),
        (2, 'Teacher'),
        (3, 'Parents'),
    )
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=3)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField('date_created', auto_now_add = True, null=True)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(default='', max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Why do you make three different tables for a user? It looks better to make one `User` model, and then make models like `Parent`, etc. that links to that `User`. It furthermore allows one to be both a parent and a teacher for example.

Comment: Those tables are from different db. I will synchronize my app with that db. The thing is that, if I have a parent and teacher with same pk, which are 2 different people, than it does not work.

Comment: When you synchronize, just append username field with the proper TYPE_CHOICE and you are good to go. There is a possibility to change the login (or user selection) mechanism as well but this would be much more complicated compared to modify the data on the input. So basically during import just construct username in a way that suits you.

Comment: thanks, that is the best solution for now, even though is has 1 tiny disadvantage: when someone changes its username to e.g. 444parent, it occupies that username if it will be created in remote parent table.

Comment: "I will synchronize my app with that db" => how ? "if I have a parent and teacher with same pk, which are 2 different people, than it does not work" => why ?

Comment: I have django rest, so I can just run script that takes all data from those tables, and in save method of user model, I will write "self.username = self.username + "parent". Then I will write signals for models that will perform http request to endpoints to perform needed tasks.